# vlookup function excel cut part of string

Tags: excel, vlookup

Guys i have a little problem. I have 2 csv files, i want to copy some data from one csv to another where id is the same. For this i use vlookupfunction but something is not good.
The orginal string in orginal csv is:

```
48 Port Managed Layer 3 Gigabit Ethernet Switch with optional 10GigE uplink and 802.3af and Legacy Power over Ethernet. Includes 48 - Copper Gigabit (1000Base-T) access ports and 2 - High Speed Expansion Slots. Provides up to 370 watts of 802.3af compliant power. Features include 802.1Q VLANs, GVRP, 802.1p QoS, 802.1w Rapid Spanning Tree, 802.3ad Link Aggregation, Auto MDI/MDI-X, CLI, HTTP GUI, SSH, SSL, RADIUS, SNMP. 19" Rackmount 1U housing. Includes AC PoE power supply. Supported expansion modules: Dual Stacking XIM (4700470F1, 4700470F2, 4700470F5), Dual SFP XIM (1700473F1), Dual SFP+ XIM (1700471F1).
```

And when i use this function

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,osnova.csv!$B$2:$AD$1660,8,0),IF(G2="","",G2))
```

I get this string:

```
48 Port Managed Layer 3 Gigabit Ethernet Switch with optional 10GigE uplink and 802.3af and Legacy Power over Ethernet. Includes 48 - Copper Gigabit (1000Base-T) access ports and 2 - High Speed Expansion Slots. Provides up to 370 watts of 802.3af compliant power. Features include 802.1Q VLANs, GVRP, 802.1p QoS, 802.1w Rapid Spanning Tree, 802. 19&quot; Rackmount 1U housing. Includes AC PoE power supply. Supported expansion modules: Dual Stacking XIM (4700470F1, 4700470F2, 4700470F5), Dual SFP XIM (1700473F1), Dual SFP+ XIM (1700471F1).
```

The difference is that i have in orginal string this part and in the copied version i lose that part:

```
.3ad Link Aggregation, Auto MDI/MDI-X, CLI, HTTP GUI, SSH, SSL, RADIUS, SNMP.
```

Can someone help me with this? Did i do something wrong in my function?

Comment: Is the function hitting a character limit?

Comment: How do you mean? I didnt know for character limit?

Comment: So use len() to check the number of characters in the source and result and then check if vlookup has a limit...

Comment: YES there is difference in length

orginal = 612characters
copy = 541 characters

Comment: @doki I cannot reproduce your problem by using dummy ID's.  The entire 612 length string is returned by VLOOKUP.  I suspect the issue is with your data.  Perhaps G2 contains the string that is being returned by your function?

Comment: @SolarMike If the character limit were exceeded, `VLOOKUP` would not be removing a substring of characters from the middle of the returned string.  Rather, it returns a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld my first comment was a question asking if that was a possibility, obviously it is not a possibility as it does not return a value error, so could it be a particular character or combination triggering something?

Comment: also some other data from the colum this function copy good with all charactrs, its just problem with some data in column :S

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Examine your data closely. Use the formula evaluation tool to see what is being returned. Create sample data that reproduces your problem that we can use for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Excel must be hitting the [character](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=vlookup%20character%20limit&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU745AU745&oq=vlookup%20char&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.5781j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) [limit](https://superuser.com/questions/247427/255-character-limit-on-vlookup) of `VLOOKUP`.  You should not be using this function in the first place, [it's broken and it sucks](https://medium.com/@cbenkendorf/why-excel-vlookup-sucks-and-what-to-use-instead-3d82e697512).  Consider using much [superior INDEX/MATCH](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/) combination `=index(osnova.csv!$H$1660, match($A2,osnova.csv!$B$2,0))`.

Comment: @doki  You should be able to edit that so it does work, hint vlookup needed column 8 for its result, so the array for index needs to be that result column...

Comment: @doki - you are right, I have corrected it and it just highlights one many problems with this functions - it makes it difficult to read.  Solar Mike have pointed you to the right direction.

Comment: `VLOOKUP`'s character limit is in `lookup_value` and, if exceeded, returns a `#VALUE!` error.  It does not remove characters in the middle of a returned string.